# OnPropertyChanged called more after WPF upgrade

Tags: wpf, binding, grid, dependency-properties

We maintain a WPF app/controls. One of the control is a grid which stores numbers, user can edit the cells.
In WPF 3.0, it works fine.
Now we moved to WPF 4.5, and the same code behaves **differently**: after editing a cell, and hitting ENTER, it causes "extra refresh" of the grid.
I debugged, and found this:

```
public List<List<double>> DoubleArray { get; set; }

private void dataGrid2D_CellEditEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
     ...
     DoubleArray[y][x] = double.Parse(textBox.Text);
     GridContent = DoubleArray; <======= [this line]
     ...
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty GridContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("GridContent", typeof(IList), typeof(GridEditor), 
                             new UIPropertyMetadata(null,GridContentPropertyChanged));

public IList GridContent
{
    get { return (IList)GetValue(GridContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(GridContentProperty, value); }
}

private static void GridContentPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditor editor = source as GridEditor;
    editor.OnGridContentChanged(e.OldValue,e.NewValue);
}

public virtual void OnGridContentChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
{
     ....
     RebindData(dataGrid);
}

private void RebindData(DataGrid2DLibrary.DataGrid2DT grid)
{
    Binding datagrid2dBinding = new Binding();
    .....
    datagrid2dBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("DoubleArray");
    grid.SetBinding(DataGrid2DT.ItemsSource2DProperty, datagrid2dBinding);
 }
```

The marked line `GridContent = DoubleArray;` runs different in WPF3 and WPF4.5.
In WPF4.5, it causes the `GridContentPropertyChanged` to fired, while in WPF3 it does not.  I guess this should be the reason of the "extra refresh".
Callstack for this "extra" call:

```
OurEditor.dll!OurEditor.GridEditor.GridEditor.OnGridContentChanged(object oldValue, object newValue) Line 345   C#
OurEditor.dll!OurEditor.GridEditor.GridEditor.GridContentPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject source, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) Line 120  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(bool isASubPropertyChange) Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(bool dependencySourcesChanged, bool initialValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange)   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RefreshValue()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.RefreshValue()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateTarget()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.EndSourceUpdate()   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateSource(object value)  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.UpdateValue()   Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateOverride()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Update()    Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.ProcessDirty()  Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Dirty() Unknown
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal)    Unknown
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value)    Unknown
OurEditor.dll!OurEditor.GridEditor.GridEditor.GridContent.set(System.Collections.IList value) Line 114  C#
OurEditor.dll!OurEditor.GridEditor.GridEditor.dataGrid2D_CellEditEnding(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) Line 674   C#
```

The XAML how this editor is used:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GridEditorTemplate">
    <ge:GridEditor IsReadOnly="{Binding IsOutput, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type vo:OutputView}}}">
        <me:GridEditor.GridContent>
            <Binding Path="TheGridValue"  Mode="TwoWay" Converter="{StaticResource gridConverter}">
            </Binding> 
         </me:GridEditor.GridContent>
    </me:GridEditor>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I am not really familiar with WPF, so any help/hint could be useful what to check/how to have the same "proper" behavior we had with WPF3.
If any additional info is needed, I can try to provide.

Comment: how about using `if(oldvalue == newValue) return;`

Comment: Yes, that might be something to consider as workaround, but I guess there should be a root cause for this changed behavior, and would be better to change according to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In WPF4.5, it causes the `GridContentPropertyChanged` to fired, while in WPF3 it does not.

Well, the `GridContentPropertyChanged` should be fired whenever the dependency property is set to a new value. This is the expected behaviour and obviously this has been fixed in newer versions of the .NET Framework. So the 4.5 behaviour is the expected one.

You may get a lot of fixes "for free" when you upgrade the .NET version. If this causes an issue in your application, your code was probably written in the wrong way originally. So you could either avoid upgrading or fixing your code as suggested by @Peter:

```
public virtual void OnGridContentChanged(object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (oldvalue == newValue)
        return;
     ....
     RebindData(dataGrid);
}
```

Comment: This suggestion won't work, as when you change any cell, obviously the `oldValue != newValue`. However, comparing `DoubleArray == newValue` will do the trick.

Comment: Well, the actual comparison was just an example. The main point is that the handler will be fired.

Comment: Thanks the clarification, I fixed by own logic, but it's clear now that why it's happening.